# How to install Kate-plugins?

Tags: python, django, plugins, kde-plasma, kate

I'm trying to install [Kate-plugins](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Kate-plugins) `pip install pysmell==0.7.3 pyplete==0.0.2 pep8==0.6.1 pyflakes==0.5.0 pyjslint==0.3.3 simplejson==2.6.1` work fine, but when I try `pip install Kate-plugins` have an error "error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kate_plugins': Permission denied". `sudo pip install Kate-plugins` installation successful.

```
sudo pip install Kate-plugins
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Kate-plugins in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pysmell==0.7.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Kate-plugins)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pep8==0.6.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Kate-plugins)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyflakes==0.5.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Kate-plugins)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyjslint==0.3.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Kate-plugins)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyplete==0.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Kate-plugins)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplejson==2.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Kate-plugins)
Cleaning up...
```

Following the instruction `ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kate_plugins/ $(kde4-config --localprefix)/share/apps/kate/pate` executing without errors.
But I don't see "Python Plugins" in: Settings > Configure Kate > Plugins.

I have KDE 4.8.5 Kate 3.8.5

And one more question: Have you know some good plugins for Python + Django + Kate?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is that this [repo](https://github.com/goinnn/Kate-plugins#information) is unmaintained. Because these plugins have been added to the official repository. The next month will be the release of the KDE 4.11 with these plugins...

It's possible that you don't see "Python Plugins" because the name of this plugin in this version was other.... Something with "Pate" or "Pâtè"

Comment: Since you're the maintainer, perhaps you can shed a light on it. There's no python plugins nor Pâtè in KDE5 (Plasma)? Have they been removed again?